# Sending GET requests from user input within Docker?

Tags: docker, http, go, get, request

I'm using Golang and trying to take user input from the CLI and send it as a GET request to localhost:8080 but I can't work out how to do it. I currently have the following and am using a Docker container:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter desired input: ")

    // Get user input
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)

    http.HandleFunc("/", doSomething)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))

    resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/?input=" + input)
    // Print response out here
}

func doSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    query := r.URL.Query().Get("input")
    // Send response
}
```

Docker file:

```
FROM golang:1.12.0-alpine3.9
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

I then start the Docker container:

docker run -it -p 8080:8081 go-app

I would like to enter in numbers in the CLI and then return a response from the HTTP server. How can I do this as the above solution doesn't work (since it doesn't make the GET request within the main() method).

Comment: `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))` --- this line is the last line that can be executed in your application. No lines after it are guaranteed to execute ever.

Comment: I know, I'm trying to figure out a way so that I can have it running and accept input from the CLI. I was thinking of multithreading it, having user input on one thread and the HTTP server on another but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Run the http server in a different goroutine

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter desired input: ")

    // Get user input
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)

    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go func() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", doSomething)
        log.Fatal(http.Serve(l, nil))
    }()

    resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/?input=" + input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Resp: %v\n", resp)
    // Print response out here
}

func doSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    query := r.URL.Query().Get("input")
    fmt.Println(query)
    // Send response
}
```

Comment: This is a race; you cannot guarantee that the server is ready to accept connections by the time http.Get is called. Use [http.Serve](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Serve) instead of ListenAndServe and create the listener in the main goroutine.

Comment: Thx @Peter . Updated according your suggestion.